# Unable to compare dates of different formats in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, datetime, sharepoint

I have to update objects in a data set by the last modified date.
The (potentially) updated objects come from a REST api call and the objects to be updated from a SharePoint list.

Unfortunately, I'm getting way different date/time formats for each identical item in PowerShell. Compare:

Rest call results: `2016-12-15T08:08:39.012+01:00`
SharePoint list: `Thursday, December 15, 2016 7:08:39 AM`

I was thinking of using the `[datetime]::ParseExact` method but a) I don't know what the input format has to be and b) if that even helps me to compare the two afterwards.

I'd appreciate your help, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can store both the date in variable and change it to the specific format for example `Get-Date $date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"` and then you can compare the dates for example

```
$date="Thursday, December 15, 2016 7:08:39 AM"
Get-Date $date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"

$date="2016-12-15T08:08:39.012+01:00"
Get-Date $date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
```

for both output would be in same format

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to address a few issues:

1. You can always use `[System.DateTime]::Parse()` for each of the formats. You don't need to use `[System.DateTime]::ParseExact()`.
2. You can use `Get-Date` instead of C#. Use native features whenever possible. `Get-Date $SomeDate` will always give you the same results with `[System.DateTime]::Parse($SomeDate)`.
3. The unnamed issue is one of the formats care about **TimeZones** but other one does not. You need to work on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Get-Date` to convert the strings to `[DateTime]` objects, which can then be easily compared:

```
$date1 = Get-Date '2016-12-15T08:08:39.012+01:00'
$date2 = Get-Date 'Thursday, December 15, 2016 7:08:39 AM'

$date1 -gt $date2
True

$date1 -lt $date2
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the explanations, that was very helpful. I managed to compare and adjust for the timezone differences the following way:

`$date1 = Get-Date '2016-12-15T08:08:39.012+01:00'
 $date2 = (Get-Date 'Thursday, December 15, 2016 7:08:39 AM').AddHours(1)`

By comparing the .DateTime property I will get the evaluation to be true:

`$date1.DateTime -eq $date2.DateTime
 True`